# Why get_user_model() return empty in Django

Tags: python, django

I've been writing a Django web app and a i create new model user, i've been writing functions login, Register.... and i need to use get_user_model(), but when i use it, it return empty
Models:

```
class Login(models.Model):
id = models.CharField(db_column='id', primary_key=True, max_length=50,unique=True)
username = models.CharField(db_column='username', unique=True, max_length=50)
password = models.CharField(db_column='password', max_length=254)
email = models.CharField(db_column='email', unique=True, max_length=50)
security_stamp = models.CharField(db_column='security_stamp', max_length=20)
last_login = models.DateTimeField(db_column='last_login')

def set_password(self,password):
    self.password = make_password(password, 'pbkdf2_test', 'md5')

def is_authenticated(self):
    return True

class Meta:
    db_table = 'Login'
```

backend:

```
def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):

    try:
        # Try to find a user matching your username
        user = Login.objects.get(username=username)          

        #  Check the password is the reverse of the username
        if check_password(password, user.password):
            # Yes? return the Django user object
            user = Login.objects.get(username=username)
            return user
        else:
            # No? return None - triggers default login failed
            return None
    except Login.DoesNotExist:
        # No user was found, return None - triggers default login failed
        return None

# Required for your backend to work properly - unchanged in most scenarios
def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return Login.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except Login.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

return get_user_model() 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6NoE.png)

i search in google and i found that must be add AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser' in setting but when i added it i have this
'REQUIRED_FIELDS' must be a list or tuple

Comment: Look at the documentation for how to extend the User model.... Login is also a very poor class name that doesn't reflect that it's a user model...

Comment: I don't understand why you've written a custom backend here at all. It doesn't do anything different from the default one. You should remove it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you for reply yes but i have some change in model user that why i create my own

Comment: That's a good reason to have a custom user model. But there is still no need for a custom backend; the built in backend will happily use your model if you set AUTH_USER_MODEL.